# Most efficient computational way in python find pairs in a list of pairs

Tags: python

I need to find if pair exists in a list of pairs.  I can use a standard for loop with if statement, but is there a more computationally efficient way?

Current my data looks like:

```py
alist = [(12970, 12980), (12970, 13000), (12970, 13012)]
pair = [12970, 13000]

for a in list:
   if a == pair:
       print("do something")
```

I have tried using the following but it did not return a match:

```py
if pair in alist:
    print("do something")
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Try `tuple(pair) in alist`. Oh, and you have an extra zero in `pair`.

Comment: See Python materials on the `in` operator.

Comment: `pair` should be defined as a tuple, not a list. Note that these two solutions wouldn't have the same behaviour anyway, since the first loop will print multiple times if the pair occurs multiple times.

Comment: Please post a complete question.  "it did not work" is not a problem specification.  From what I see, the problem is that you compared a list against a sequence of tuples.

Comment: @Adam if you have the list sorted, say by the second element of each tuple (or by both if the first element is not guaranteed to be the same), then you use binary search, which is O(logn).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pair` is a **list** of two integers.

`alist` has elements that are **tuples**.

Since these are not even of the same base type, they will not compare as equal.

Try

```
alist = [(12970, 12980), (12970, 13000), (12970, 13012)]
pair = (12970, 13000)    # tuple, not list
if pair in list:
    ...
```

If your problem requirements don't let you change the original values, then cast the type in-line:

```
if tuple(pair) in list:
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `alist` is sorted you can use `bisect` which should have complexity O(log n).

Copying from module docs:

```
import bisect

def index(a, x):
    'Locate the leftmost value exactly equal to x'
    i = bisect.bisect_left(a, x)
    if i != len(a) and a[i] == x:
        return i
    raise ValueError

index(alist, (12970, 13000))
```

If there is no element found you will get `ValueError`

You could also go with converting `alist` to set.
Then the average complexity should be O(1) on lookup